# Magento 2 : Get backorders and update backorders status by specific product

Tags: magento2, backorder

I want to get back orders by specific product id and update product's back orders status by specific product.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to inject `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface` in your construct for get backorders details by specific product Id. Add this below code in your construct :

```
protected $productRepository;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
) {
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
}
```

Now, You need to add this below code in your function.

> **Get backorders by specific product :**

```
$productId = 1;
$product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
$productStock = $product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem();
echo $productStock['backorders'];
```

> **Update backorders by specifc product :**

```
$productId = 1;
$product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
$stockData = ['backorders' => 1, 'use_config_backorders' => 1];
$product->setStockData($stockData);
$this->productRepository->save($product);
```

---

### UPDATE:

You can body value which you pass in API get this by this below code :

```
protected $request;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request $request
){
$this->request = $request;  
}

$postBodyData = $this->request->getBodyParams();
```

Hope, It will helpful for you.

Comment: I added this code in API and need to get data which pass in body text. How to get that value?

Comment: check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks !! It's working..

Answer (score 2):

Try below code

```
$obj = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();  
$stockRegistry = $obj->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface');
$stockitem = $stockRegistry->getStockItem($_product->getId(),$_product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
echo "Backorder: "; echo $stockitem->getBackorders(); echo '<br>';
```

Comment: How to update also?

Comment: I checked in "cataloginventory_stock_item" table for product id 1, and there are backorders field value is "1" But, still it returns 0